# Angular Material: issue with mat-select

Tags: angular, angular-material, dropdown

Im using a simple dropdown from Angular Material with the purpose of triggering an event/function on selection (this case an api call). I have tried almost everything, saw plenty of posts and still im missing something

The HTML:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Choose a camera</mat-label>
  <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selected"  (ngModelChange)="test()">
    <mat-option  *ngFor="let c of cameras" [value]="c.name">
      {{c.name}} 
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

The ts:

```
export class MoviesComponent implements OnInit {
  selected:string;

  test() { 
    console.log(this.selected);
  }
}
```

This is very simple, and one of plenty of aproaches, but nothing is working! Any ideas?

Comment: Material for angular is so full of holes, that you need to practice and write just in material for a month, and do nothing else, just in order to master it. It beats the whole purpose of being a reliable out-of-the-box set of form elements to use instantly and with ease. It is a complete failure. I've been having issues with mat-select for while too. It is a complete bull kit and should be avoided. Sorry fanbois, someone had to say it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options. Either a model form or a reactive form.

#### Option 1: Model form

Controller

```js
export class MoviesComponent implements OnInit {
  selected:string;
  
  test() {
    // API call here
    console.log(this.selected) 
  }
}
```

Template

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Choose a camera</mat-label>
  <mat-select [(value)]="selected" (selectionChange)="test()">
  <!-- OR <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selected" (ngModelChange)="test()"> -->
    <mat-option *ngFor="let c of cameras" [value]="c.name">
      {{c.name}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

#### Option 2: Reactive form

Controller

```js
export class MoviesComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  completed$ = new Subject<any>();
  selected: string;
  selectedControl = new FormControl(this.selected);
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.selectedControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      takeUntil(this.completed$),
      switchMap(selected => {
        console.log(selected);
        // return API call here
      })
    ).subscribe(
      response => {
        // handle respone from API
      },
      error => {
        // handle error from API
      }
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.completed$.next();
    this.completed$.complete();
  }
}
```

Template

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Choose a camera</mat-label>
  <mat-select [formControl]="selectedControl">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let c of cameras" [value]="c.name">
      {{c.name}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: thank you all for the solutions, the check goes to the most accurate answer :)